# How to create dynamic href in react render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a list of posts. For each post I would like to render an anchor tag with the post id as part of the href string.

```
render: function(){
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                this.props.posts.map(function(post){
                    return <li key={post.id}><a href='/posts/'{post.id}>{post.title}</a></li>
                })
            }
        </ul>
    );
```

How do I do it so that each post has href's of `/posts/1`, `/posts/2` etc?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
href={'/posts/' + post.id}
```

The JSX syntax allows either to use strings or expressions `({...})` as values. You cannot mix both. Inside an expression you can, as the name suggests, use any JavaScript expression to compute the value.

Comment: works great, but if you're using a compiler like babel, then template strings are more elegant.

Comment: what if its a mailto ?

Comment: @tallgirltaadaa: no difference. JSX / JavaScript doesn’t care about the actual value of the string.

Answer (score 104):

You can use ES6 backtick syntax too

```
<a href={`/customer/${item._id}`} >{item.get('firstName')} {item.get('lastName')}</a>
```

[More info on es6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: for this to work is it necessary to use ` and not ' ?

Comment: Yes the backtick is a new es6 syntax for string interpolation, Updated my answer with a link

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Felix's answer,

```
href={`/posts/${posts.id}`}
```

would work well too. This is nice because it's all in one string.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this ?

Create another item in post such as **post.link** then assign the link to it before send **post** to the render function.

```
post.link = '/posts/+ id.toString();
```

So, the above render function should be following instead.

```
return <li key={post.id}><a href={post.link}>{post.title}</a></li>
```