# Redux-form, how to set the Field name to a dynamic string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Redux-form is not allowing me to set the Field name to an integer as it requires a string... How can I set the redux-form Field name to something the API can then use to record the user's option selected per Talent.

```
        <Field
          name='talent_id[' + {field.talent_id} + ']'
          component={renderField}
          field={field}
          />
```

This is not working, I'm getting `Syntax error: Unexpected token` with the `+`

**Talents.rb**

```
id | Title
1 | Jumping
2 | Skipping
3 | Running
```

My API, returns Talents#Index like so:

```
[
 {"id":1,"title":"Jumping"},
 {"id":2,"title":"Skipping Rope"},
 {"id":3,"title":"Running"},
 {"id":4,"title":"Something Else"}
]
```

I then amusing the above to build a form that can later be submitted to the server.

```
<div>
   <label>Jumping</label>
   <select name="1">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">XXX</option>
      <option value="2">YYY</option>
      <option value="3">ZZZ</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Skipping Rope</label>
   <select name="2">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">XXX</option>
      <option value="2">YYY</option>
      <option value="3">ZZZ</option>
   </select>
</div>
....
```

Comment: Nothing to do with redux-form. Your syntax is invalid JSX. Try `name={ 'talent_id[' + field.talent_id + ']' }`. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic href in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567729/how-to-create-dynamic-href-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are use using ES5, simply like this:

```
  <Field
      name={`talent_id[${field.talent_id}]`}
      component={renderField}
      field={field}
  />
```