# React- Active next tab while clicking button on this code

Tags: reactjs

I have 5 tabs on my page. each tab contain different data.

i have button inside every tab, basically want to active next tab to show content when user clicks on that button.

```
render(){
         return (
        <div>
            <h1>Tell us About yourslef</h1>
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-menu-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" className="text-uppercase active">Personal</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-menu-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" className="text-uppercase">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-menu-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" className="text-uppercase">Verification</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-menu-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" className="text-uppercase">Preferences</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-menu-5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" className="text-uppercase">Notifications</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div id="tab-menu-2">
                    <h1>This is Personal Tab</h1>
                    <button type="submit">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div id="tab-menu-3">
                    <h1>This is Contact Tab</h1>
                    <button type="submit">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div id="tab-menu-4">
                    <h1>This is Verification Tab</h1>
                    <button type="submit">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div id="tab-menu-5">
                    <h1>This is Notifications Tab</h1>
                    <button type="submit">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )   
}
```

How i can do that??

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html

I would suggest to look at these documents to see more about relations property types and objects. 
[How to create dynamic href in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567729/how-to-create-dynamic-href-in-react-render-function)
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html|
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn|

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#function-components
You can pattern your functions on Js to best handle the pages on import.